# What roll puts out a fire?

Tags: savage-worlds

If a character is on fire, what they would they roll to put themselves out? How long should this take? A spot fire versus being completely engulfed might require different amounts of effort and difficulty.

For reference, *Savage Worlds Deluxe* has a pretty straightforward section on catching on fire and that fire getting worse.

> Anytime something flammable is hit by fire, roll 1d6. On a 6, the target catches fire. Very flammable targets, such as a scarecrow, catch fire on a 4-6. Volatile targets, such as a person soaked in gasoline, catch fire on anything but a 1. Each round after a victim catches fire (at the beginning of his action), roll as if checking to see if the victim catches fire again. If he does, the fire grows in intensity and does the damage listed above each round.

My initial idea was just taking an action to try an Agility roll, maybe with a bonus for "stop drop and roll" and the like.

Comment: Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange!

Comment: The "Stop, Drop, and Roll."

Comment: mxyplk, perfect! I came here to say that too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It is up to the GM and the situation

*Savage Worlds* does not have any built in rule for putting out a fire, largely because fires can come from all sorts of sources. Putting out a common household fire may be different than putting out a magical waterproof fire.

Stop, drop, and roll will probably work in most situations, and if I were your GM, I would think that an Agility roll would be reasonable, perhaps with a penalty if you're in an area that isn't conducive to it. [This Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/savageworlds/comments/1juji2/what_skillattribute_for_attempting_to_put_out/) suggests other options including:

- A common knowledge roll (especially if there are buckets of water around)
- Strength or Vigor rolls for hauling buckets of water quickly
- Spirit rolls to deal with being in such a scary situation
- No roll, but it takes an action

Again, it depends on the type of the fire and the situation, but ultimately it's the GM's call.